# How to repair linux after failed to start file system

Tags: linux, arch-linux, filesystems, hard-disk, initrd

I have problem with my linux. I always had small problem with my HHD but my PC always could works correctly but yesterday its stuck and I decided to reboot it. After rebooting I get this error.

```
[FAILED] Failed to start File System 6-53ec-49bb-8b46-0913583825fb. 
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /sysroot. 
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Initrd Root File System.
```

[image: The screen image here]

However, I can boot my Windows, which is on the same HDD as Linux.

Please help me fix my computer.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Boot a live Linux from CD/DVD/USB pendrive and check the Linux file systems of your harddisk. A harddisk can have errors in a specific region which may explain that you can still boot Windows but not Linux. If it is a hardware failure, the problems can get bigger. I suggest to backup all important as soon as possible.

Comment: ... Looks like arch linux shot itself in the foot in an attempt to 'secure' itself by locking out the root account by default. Unless that's something you did deliberately at some point in the past?

Comment: @Bodo, thank you for your comment. How I can check the file systems? 
P.S.
I also think that Shadur is right because one year ago I also have such a problem, but then I can just repair my packages with one command(now I don't remember that command) and run Linux. Maybe now because Linux kernel is updated I can't just repair that packages and maybe I should boot with LiveUSB and run that command from there.

Comment: @Shadur, as I mentioned above it's can just be regarding damage of packages and because the new kernel blocks me I just should run from LiveUSB and try to run a command which will repair my packages.

Comment: @Tomas It may depend a bit on the setup of your Linux system and the live/rescue Linux you want to use. `fsck` is the command to check a file system. Of course you have to find out which partitions (or logical volumes) are relevant for your Linux system. See e.g. https://www.golinuxcloud.com/e2fsck-repair-filesystem-in-rescue-mode-ext4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very grateful to all of you for your help, but nevertheless, I solved this issue in a different way.

In my case, the solution to this problem was simply booting from LiveUSB and then running the command `fsck -f /dev/sd##`. This completely solved my problem.

I also want to add a solution for another problem that I encountered while solving this problem. The problem was that for some reason the recorded USB was not recognized by my computer and I had to write the Linux image to another USB, after which the problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR: Your system is hosed and you're going to need to boot from a live USB image to even *start* to figure out what went wrong

Two things can be inferred from the screenshot you've shared:

1. Your system suffered a critical error during the bootup phase, probably involving the filesystem, which causes the init process (in this case `systemd`) to refuse to proceed in anything but emergency console mode.
2. It can't actually *start* emergency console mode because the system has been configured to lock root out *completely* -- meaning that `sulogin` refuses to proceed.

#2 is *probably* something you did yourself at some point in the past, either by accident or by following well-intentioned instructions about securing a server. At least I hope it is.

At any rate, this system is hosed - it won't boot until root logs in and fixes whatever went wrong with the filesystem, but root *can't* login.

Depending on how much customization you've done with that system and how recent your last backup was, I recommend you load a live USB image, mount your partitions and attempt to exfil as much of your data as you can rescue, then wipe and reinstall, assuming that the drive didn't have a hardware failure.

It *might* be possible to rescue the system entirely, but that's almost certainly going to be an incredible amount of fuss and work that I'm not sure you're up to.

Comment: I think this is not about the boot phase, and I also don't think it is about setting up the system so that it can block me because I don't remember ever setting that up.

Comment: A year ago I had a similar problem, but then I could log in as root and run a command to restore packages. I think I am currently facing such a situation, but since the kernel version has changed, I get a message that root login is denied (or something like that, I was not very clear about the error message). It seems if I just boot via LiveUSB and run the package restore command, then everything will be solved.
If this method doesn't work, I'll let you know.

Comment: I explained *precisely* what the error message is about. Check the `sulogin` manpage if you like, it describes this exact situation and in what case it behaves this way.

Comment: Ok, thank you for you help.